# Angular 2/4 need a Typescript regex to only allow numbers to be entered into input textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

In my Angular 4 application I have this input box in which I ONLY want numbers...  0-9 to be entered..  otherwise I want it to clear out onkeyup

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" (keyup)="numbersOnly($event)"  placeholder="0000000000" formControlName="phone" maxlength="10"/>
```

Above works to call this function in the component 
but it is not working to prevent letters.

```
numbersOnly(val) {
    let y = this.trackerForm.controls['phone'].value
    y.value = y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');

    console.log('y', y);

}
```

1. Is .value the wrong approach?
2. Should I be using  event preventdefault?

The console log for  'y' shows correctly.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ReactiveForm, you should understand that **FormConrtol's value only has a `getter`**.

If you want to change formControl's value, use `patchValue` or `setValue`.

```
let y = this.trackerForm.controls['phone'];
this.trackerForm.controls['phone'].patchValue(y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
// OR
this.trackerForm.controls['phone'].setValue(y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
```

Refer **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TPePTWZiT7GmB76d1sqA?p=preview)**.

Comment: I see that your demo works,  but it stills lets me enter letters and it throws errors

Comment: @JeremyMiller This is because you are using `keyUp` event, so the event will fire until keyup.

Comment: So how can i fix

Comment: @JeremyMiller this is a little tricky, but you can track keyCode and use `$event.preventDefault()` to prevent from `unnumber character` been typed, also you have to do this at keydown. See demo at my answer, I have updated.

Comment: so ya,  i used the keydown the the event , and then `if (e.keyCode > 57 | e.keyCode < 48) {
      e.preventDefault();  
    }`

Comment: @JeremyMiller Since this is a little tricky, you may have to consider the set of keys which should be prevent from. I just provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a model on the input and pass that into your function with the event. Change the model instead of the event value. Also your solution may not be working because the input probably has the value updated on the (keypress) event.

Answer (score 0):

```
let y = this.trackerForm.controls['phone'].value
                                            ^^^^^
y.value = y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
   ^^^^
```

You are already taking the value.

Change it to

```
let y = this.trackerForm.controls['phone'];
y.value = y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
```

You use `ngModel` instead.

```
<input type="number" (keyup)="numbersOnly()"  placeholder="0000000000" formControlName="phone" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="value"/>


value = "";
numbersOnly() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: `y.value = y.value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, '');`      error in visual studio saying that value cannot be assigned  as it must be a constant or something

Comment: the better way is using `ngModel` this is the recommended way

Answer (score 0):

To access the value of the input field, use `ngModel` ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel))

For form validation, have a look at the [built-in tools](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation). If you use these, you can simply use the HTML attribute `pattern` to achieve a validation of an input field by a regular expression. ([documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp))

Updated code:

```
<input type="number" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="0000000000" pattern="[0-9.-]*" maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" #phoneNumber="ngModel"/>
```

Please note that you need to define a new field named `phoneNumber` in your component.

Comment: but i don't want another field, i have formcontrol inside a formgroup,   i am using  `phone`    why do i need to create another field?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of things angular has directives that listen to the events coming from components.

If you have your input mapped to a model then the way you assign the value will not be reflected into model. So that should be taken care of as well.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[restrict]',
})
export class RestrictDirective {


  constructor(private control: NgControl) {}        

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event.target'])
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event.target'])
  private onInputEvent(input) {
    if (input.value) {
      let truncated = input.value.replace(PATTERN, ''); //put your pattern here
      // change value only if it contains disallowed characters
      if (truncated !== input.value) {
        this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(truncated); //write to model
        this.control.viewToModelUpdate(truncated);        //write to view       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then just get to use the directive in the input

```
<input type="text" restrict/>
```

For integers the pattern would be

```
const PATTERN = /[\D]/g;
```

Comment: NgControl is from where?

Answer (score 0):

Improving Damask's answer. If we are using Reactive Forms, I's necesary the last line: "this.control.control.setValue(truncated); "

```
<input type="text" [restrict]="'[^0-9]'" />
```

The directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[restrict]',
})
export class RestrictDirective {

  regexp:any;
  @Input('restrict') 
  set pattern(value)
  {
    this.regexp=new RegExp(value,"g");
  }

  constructor(private control: NgControl) {}        

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event.target'])
  private onInputEvent(input) {
    if (input.value) {
      let truncated = input.value.replace(this.regexp, ''); 
      if (truncated !== input.value) {
        this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(truncated); //write to model
        this.control.viewToModelUpdate(truncated);        //write to view 
        this.control.control.setValue(truncated);  //send to control

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a simple directive something like this

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumberOnly]'
})
export class NumberOnlyDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onInput(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9]/;
    const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);

    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

import this in your module

and in HTML

```
<input type="number" appNumberOnly placeholder="0000000000" formControlName="phone" maxlength="10"/>
```

Also inside your component.ts, inside `formBuilder` you can have something like this

```
 phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern('[6-9]\\d{9}'), Validators.required])],
```